# Trying to overwrite / append editor-style.css from parent theme in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am using the good old twenty eleven for a simple job and overwrite styles using a child.

The Problem is, that editor styles are not overwritten when i add an editor-child.css in the child theme folder.
Adding add_editor_style in the child themes functions.php (wrapped in after_setup_theme) doesn't seem to work. Can't I load multiple editor styles or what is the problem here? I can't figure out how I can overwrite this ugly twenty eleven editor css in gutenberg. It might even be better to disable it, but even that doesn't work using remove_editor_style. And I can't find anything on the subject using google or stackoverflow.

```
<?php
// In the child theme functions.php. I simply want to use the style.css by the child theme as an extra editor style
function wysiwyg_styles() {
    add_editor_style( get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wysiwyg_styles');
?>
```

No css is loaded in the admin (after deleting chache AND cookies)

Answer (score 1):

What happen is that you're using the wrong action hook... you should be using the **[admin_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/)** hook.

Try doing it like this.. and check if it works for you:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function () {
  wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/pathToYour.css');
});

// If the above does not work change get_stylesheet_directory_uri() for get_template_directory_uri()
```

Hope this can help, good luck.

Comment: All solutions I could find involving `add_editor_style` would not work.  But this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try instead:

```
add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );
add_editor_style( 'style-editor.css' );
```

in your **functions.php**. Haven’t checked if it works with a child theme though.

More information here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/themes/theme-support/